# how to connect three tables to one table's id in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, associations

i'm building an app using nodejs,express and sequelize. in an api i want to get data from 4 different table with one pid as input. i'm trying to associate . i'm following an mvc flow. how to table 1

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

// const machine_data = require("./machine_data");

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('patient_data', {
      sl_no: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      
      },
      patient_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
        allowNull: false
      },
      p_id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false,
      
      
    
     
    },
    
    {
      associate:function(modals){
        patient_data.hasMany(modals.master_session,{ foreignKey: 'p_id' });
        patient_data.hasMany(modals.graph_data,{ foreignKey: 'pid' });
        patient_data.hasMany(modals.vital_data,{ foreignKey: 'master_id' })
      },
    },
    
    {
     sequelize,
     tableName: 'patient_data'
   });
 };

Table 2
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('master_session', {
      master_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        
  
      },
      session_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(35),
        allowNull: true
      },
 {
      associate:function(modals){
        master_session.belongsTo(modals.patient_data,{ foreignKey: 'p_id' });
       
      },
    },


    {
     sequelize,
     tableName: 'master_session'
   });
 };

table 3
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('graph_data', {
      sl_no: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        foreignKey:true,
        refereces:{
          model:'patient_data',
          key:'p_name'
        }
        
       
  
      },
      document: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(2000),
        allowNull: true
      },

      pid: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true
      },

      session: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true
      },
          
    },
    {
      associate:function(modals){
        graph_data.hasMany(modals.patient_data,{ foreignKey: 'pid' });
      
      },
    },
    
    {
     sequelize,
     tableName: 'graph_data'
   });
 };
```

and there's a table 4 with same structure as T3 . Before using associations i used reference as in the code to set foreign key and manually connected this in phpmyadmin. now i got confused with what to do. I want to pass p_id from table 1 in my req.body and fetch data from rest tables. any input is appreciated.
regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the file where you want to fetch your data, import your `PatientModel` and the others. And you could do the following.

```
patientModel.findAll({
 include: [
  {
   model: masterSessionModel,
   attributes: // attributes from master_session
  },
  {
   model: graphDataModel,
   attributes: // attributes from graphData
  },
  // other associated models
 ]
}).then(myData => { // do something with it })
```

Find the time to read more in the sequelize docs over here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#eager-loading-example

Comment: i have an index.js file where i have my db defined, do i have to put this over there or in my api?

Comment: yes your DB should be imported in the file where you want to define your API returns... your controller basically.

Comment: \but i already imported in my controller like this  import models from "../models"; that means every model is accesible right?

Comment: Each model is an object where function like `findAll`, `findOne` , `count` ... are methods of that object. How you import your models can be done in whatever way you like, just make sure your apply those method to the object `Model` defined. This should be helpful https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html